# How the silverlight business template can login into the application?

Tags: c#, silverlight, authentication, mvvm

I'm a bit confuse when the user is trying to login into the `Silverligh Business application`.

In my database, I've got two tables called `Students` and `Teachers`, and I've got a view called UsersView where I do an union between these two tables (and this view or query, has just as attribute Id).

I need to use this view in my silverlight business application to verify if the user exists. I've seen that many projects are using WFC RIA Services, in fact I was thinking to call directly to my database but I'm really confuse.

Can someone tells me if it's necessary to login through AuthenticationBase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Silverlight cannot call directly to a database since it's a client side application. It HAS to go through an intermediary WCF service, or you can use WCF RIA services to get some functionality out of the box. A silverlight business application template should come with two projects, a silverlight one that produces a client side .xap and a web project. If you go to properties on the silverlight app it should show a RIA services link to the web project. If you run it, it should (if I am not mistaken) create a temp database using a sql express instance to login and validate users. So, long story short. Yes, you have to login using AuthenticationBase. Logins can only happen on the server. So you have to wait for the silverlight app to communicate to the server, validate against the db and then submit a response through RIA. Hope that helps.

Comment: Oh yeah, I've got the point. So, according to you, do all my sql querys should be calls since the web project, right? I mean, my entity model should remain in web project.

Comment: Yes. You should have a DomainService class that facilitates communication between the two